# How to change gridview cell background color based on its value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I need to change the background color of the cells of my gridview, but it doesn't work.

```
Protected Sub OnRowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView2.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        For Each er As GridViewRow In GridView2.Rows
            If er.Cells(4).Text = "Formation" Then
                er.Cells(4).BackColor = Color.Red
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

How do I change the background color of a cell based on its value?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Protected Sub OnRowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView2.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            If e.Row.Cells(4).Text = "Formation" Then
                e.Row.Cells(4).BackColor = Color.Red
            End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Also put a break point on

```
If e.Row.Cells(4).Text = "Formation" Then
```

and check the value of `e.Row.Cells(4).Text` and make sure it is really = `"Formation"`, maybe you need to get the value of the label that is in Cells(4).

Comment: Keep in mind OnRowDataBound event is fired for each row in your gridview so no need to put it in a foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

try the `CellFormatting` event and remove the for each in it. The event runs for every cell.

```
Private Sub grd_CellFormatting(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles GridView2.CellFormatting
    If GridView2.Item(4,e.RowIndex).Value = "Formation" Then
        e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
    End If
End Sub
```